# Unable to open browser and navigate to URL on remote Web Server through SauceLabs in Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio, saucelabs

I'm unable to execute remote tests due to being unable to open browser error.

The access key and cloud platform configs are fine.

````
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:60)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$openBrowser.call(Unknown Source)
    at ListClassScenario.run(ListClassScenario:13)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1558267636783.run(TempTestCase1558267636783.groovy:21)

```Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: No browserName or device specified in session request. Please check our platforms documentation (https://saucelabs.com/docs/platforms): {'username': 'T007', 'platform': 'macOS 10.14', 'version': '74', 'proxy': {'proxyType': 'direct'}, 'browserName ': 'Chrome', 'accesskey': 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX894f5fa4'}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you providing information about the browser, version and OS? The error suggests you are not. In order to use Saucelabs you need to set DesiredCapabilities to the RemoteWebDriver for the desired browser:

````
    baseUrl = config.get("baseUrl").toString();

    String platform = config.get("platform").toString();
    String browser = config.get("browser").toString();
    String browserVersion = config.get("browserVersion").toString();
    String recordVideo = config.get("recordVideo").toString();
    String recordScreenshots = config.get("recordScreenshots").toString();
    String build = config.get("build").toString();
    String tags = config.get("tags").toString();

    logger.info(testName + ": Creating new RemoteWebDriver with the following settings: "
        + platform + ", " + browser + ", " + browserVersion);

    DesiredCapabilities caps = getDesiredCapabilitiesForBrowser(browser);
    caps.setCapability("platform", platform);
    caps.setCapability("browserVersion", browserVersion);
    caps.setCapability("timeZone", "Denver");
    caps.setCapability("name", testName);
    caps.setCapability("recordVideo", recordVideo);
    caps.setCapability("recordScreenshots", recordScreenshots);
    caps.setCapability("build", build);
    caps.setCapability("tags", tags);
    caps.setCapability("commandTimeout", 600);
    caps.setCapability("idleTimeout", 1000);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(getRemoteSauceLabsAddress(), caps);```
````